# Delay audio for specific device

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, speakers

Let me first explain why I need to achieve this - maybe this leads to an alternative solution I didn't think of.

I want to play a song through my normal speakers and an additional radio speaker. Therefore I bought an FM transmitter which I connected to my computer. On my computer, I configured my normal speakers as default audio device and tunneled my audio through the *Stereo Mix* recorder to my Radio transmitter, which is the Default Communication Device (see [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/output-audio-to-multiple-devices-in-windows-10/b284def2-d684-4f1f-87a0-f562f556aedd) for additional information). However, the tunnelling takes some time, which results in a slight delayed sound from my radio. My idea on how to solve this issue was to delay the output for my normal speakers, so that the sound is played simultaneously on my speakers and my radio.

I'm mainly using Spotify, but it'd be cool, if all audio output was delayed for this device. I don't care if the solution to this problem is a bit hacky or if I have to write a software for myself to accomplish this task (even though superuser wouldn't be quite the right site then) either. I'm using 64 Bit Windows 10, if you need additional information, feel free to ask.

Comment: This always seems to be a struggle on Windows. [Jack](http://jackaudio.org/faq/jack_on_windows.html) might be the best start though I've never actually tested it myself. On Mac there's [Audio Hijack](https://www.rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/) which, though marketed as a 'recorder,' actually makes this type of routing simple; just drag & drop. Essentially you need to be able to plug in a delay after your split, which I've never seen done on Windows.

Comment: This post looks like a duplicate of [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/626016/playback-identical-audio-to-multiple-devices). Try the solutions in there : (1) Passing speakers from Stereo Mix, (2) Use [Voicemeeter Banana](https://www.vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/banana.htm).

Comment: @harrymc Even though it isn't a duplicate (The page you pointed out wanted to achieve something, which I solved, but which resulted in a new problem) and your first solution is the solution, that actually led to my problem, the second solution seems to work for me, as the delay doesn't exist using Voicemeeter Banana. It does not, however, answer the actual question. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Products such as Voicemeeter Banana seem like a safer solution, since a manually introduced delay is not a very precise solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My personal opinion is that adding a delay to the computer audio is not a precise
solution, for two reasons :

- There is no way that you can measure exactly the required delay
- Such a delay will be confusing for everyday work with the computer.

I suggest instead using a software product that specializes in mixing audio
and can solve the delay problem without introducing new problems.

An example product is the free
[VB-Audio VoiceMeeter Banana](https://www.vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/banana.htm).

---

The
[VoiceMeeter Banana User Manual](https://www.vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/VoicemeeterBanana_UserManual.pdf)
describes how to add an action via MACRO Buttons (page 29):

> Delivered and installed with Voicemeeter, MACRO BUTTONS Application allows
>   creating programmable button to control Voicemeeter parameters.
>   It is displaying several (4 to 80) push or 2 positions buttons with a
>   title / sub title and the possibility to assign a keyboard shortcut /
>   mouse / Game pad / MIDI message or even Audio Trigger.
>
> MACRO Button is an independent application using Voicemeeter Remote API. It is also demonstrating the capability to develop a client application to control Voicemeeter by program.

One of the programmable actions does a delay on the strip numbered *i* :

[image: delay]

I have no experience with the product, but I believe that you could use
this feature to introduce an audio delay.

Comment: I still have a problem with this answer, as it doesn't answer the question from the title. It won't help others, who searched for delaying audio for one specific device, that found this SO thread as a search result. It solves my problem, but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I think the problem with the question, as worded, is that instead of stating the problem, you asked how to implement one solution that came to your mind. I then answered to the base problem instead of the stated question. You could edit the post to state the base problem, but it's your post and your decision, not mine.

Comment: I still think it'd be quite interesting to know, how to delay audio for a specific device, and playing audio simultaniously is an already answered question, so I'd only make a duplicate of my original question.

Comment: Well, it seems from the manual that VoiceMeeter Banana can also introduce delays up to 500ms ...

Comment: Feel free to describe how to do this in an answer, and you'll receive the bounty.

Comment: The feature is described from the manual, but not tested.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an easier solution.

On page 65 of the manual, it says this:

[image]

So you can change the settings directly here for the audio outputs, without creating a Macro Button (keep in mind the max delay is 500ms, so if your lag is more than that then unfortunately this won't help much):

[image: Add delay to audio buses]